# Issue in inflating a view dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, view, layout-inflater

I am adding a layout dynamically to current view. Even if but problem is that even if i had more then two values in cursor Only one view is inflated.

It means old data is overridden. But i want to add new view per record in `phoneCrsr`.

What I'm doing wrong  ???

```
            Cursor phoneCrsr = database.rawQuery(phoneSql, null);
            while(phoneCrsr.moveToNext()){
                phone_number = new ArrayList<String>();                 
                String number = phoneCrsr.getString(phoneCrsr.getColumnIndex(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_PHN_NUMBER));

                if(!number.isEmpty()){
                    phone_number.add(number);                   

                    LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    View view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.phone_number_textview, null);

                    // fill in any details dynamically here
                    TextView phoneTv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.phone_number);
                    phoneTv.setText(number);

                    // insert into main view
                    LinearLayout phoneLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.phone_info);
                    phoneLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    ((ViewGroup) phoneLayout).addView(view, 0, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

                    //phoneLayout.setPadding(20,0,0, 0);
                    //phoneLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);      
                }                   
                Log.e("PHONE DETAIL:",phone_number.toString());
            }
            phoneCrsr.close();
```

Comment: you need to create a view per record? Why infalte a view with textview. Use listview with textviews its dynamic

Comment: @Raghunandan :Because my outer view is `scrollview` , it read somewhere that i shouldn't use `listview` inside 'scrollview'.

Comment: then there is no need for scrollview coz listview scrolls by itself

Comment: Its needed as its content can increase than the actual height of main screen. That's the different thing. All what i have is this to solve the issue i'm facing.

Comment: listview can also scroll. I do not understand what you are saying. Any way good luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add the view to your "main" layout, you're telling it to `FILL_PARENT` in both directions:

```
((ViewGroup) phoneLayout).addView(view, 0, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

If you add a view that fills an entire `LinearLayout`, that's all you'll ever see. When you add another one, it's "off the edge" in one direction(depending on `orientation`). If you're trying to add them vertically, change the height to `WRAP_CONTENT`. For a horizontal layout, change the width.

You also might want to simplify your `addView` call in general. It shouldn't be necessary to cast it to `ViewGroup`, for one thing. You can also skip the `LayoutParams` constructor completely and just pass a width and height directly to the parent with a [simpler call](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View,%20int,%20int%29). Something like this should work:

```
phoneLayout.addView(view, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
```

All in all, though, Raghunandan's comment is the best "answer". You should probably be using a `ListView` for this, since it's exactly what it was designed for.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Your comments about layout orientation solved my problem.